# Automatic weighting on my model is all over the place

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I am a beginner/hobbyist who has some very basic experience with modelling and armatures/posing. I have been scouring the forums for a while here and there, and I see people with similar issues to mine and yet none of the solutions offered to them appear to help my problem.

You see, whenever I parent my armature to my mesh using automatic weights, the weighting is all over the place, with results as odd as bones in the arm affecting the leg on the opposite side, or some bones having no influence on the mesh at all. And i'm really unsure what could be causing it.

[image: Here is an example where I mess about with the posing on the L leg, but it's contorting the entire lower body and actually influencing the R leg more. The entire model is this messy.]

[image: And here's an example where the vertex group and bone for the L forearm is actually influencing the ipsilateral shoulder and contralateral forearm - everything but the actual forearm area it as meant to.]

Things I have done to try and sort it out:

- Recalculated normals of the mesh
- Made sure every modifier (mirror, subdivision) was applied to my mesh before parenting
- Set the rest pose of the mesh as the pose that would be parented
- Eliminated all doubles from my mesh
- Ensured that all bones were named correctly in terms of L and R sides (used symmetrize on the mesh to save time)

This is not a bone heat weighting error. It appears to be a mesh issue as even when importing and applying similar armatures from other projects, the results are still aberrant, but honestly I don't know what's occurring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems that the images don't show the descriptions: The first one is an example of how posing a limb on one side influences a much larger area than intended and more so on the opposite side. The second is showing what the vertex groups and weighting looks like, with the example showing how the R forearm is affecting everything apart from itself. The entire model is as messy as this with every bone.

Comment: Check that scale (And position and rotation) is applied to the mesh and armature

Comment: Thanks for the help man, sorry for replying so late. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find out what you meant, so I decided to knuckle down and finally learn how to weight paint manually. I'm happy with my result and I learnt a lot from it!!